# Connect SAS EG to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sas

I have never tried to connect to SQL Server before (and not that great at coding).
I tried to read some stuff on the internet - this is how far I am:
I have made a connection in the ODBC Data Source Administration and the test was successfull and i called the database: fpt

Snapshot  [image]:

Afterwards I started a program in SAS EG and coded (I use windows SQL authentication, so cahnged username and password to X) :

```
LIBNAME test ODBC DSN=fpt user=X pw=X
```

in the log i get the following error and cannot figure out why?

```
1          ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
2          OPTIONS PAGENO=MIN;
3          %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL='Program (6)';
4          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH='C:\Users\g46973\Desktop\test.egp';
5          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME='test.egp';
6          %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
7          
8          ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
9          OPTIONS DEV=ACTIVEX;
10         GOPTIONS XPIXELS=0 YPIXELS=0;
11         FILENAME EGSR TEMP;
12         ODS tagsets.sasreport13(ID=EGSR) FILE=EGSR
13             STYLE=HtmlBlue
14             STYLESHEET=(URL="file:///C:/Program%20Files/SASHOME/SASEnterpriseGuide/7.1/Styles/HtmlBlue.css")
15             NOGTITLE
16             NOGFOOTNOTE
17             GPATH=&sasworklocation
18             ENCODING=UTF8
19             options(rolap="on")
20         ;
NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR
21         
22         GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;
23         LIBNAME test ODBC DSN=fpt user=fptreader pw=XXXXXXXX
24         
25         GOPTIONS NOACCESSIBLE;
           ________
           22
ERROR: Libref TEST is not assigned.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
ERROR 22-7: Invalid option name GOPTIONS.

26         %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL=;
27         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH=;
28         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME=;
29         %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
30         
31         ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
32         ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
33         
34         
35         QUIT; RUN;
36
```

Any awesome programmer who can help?

Comment: Is EG on a server or running on your desktop?

Comment: @Reeza It's on my desktop.

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be related to the code you've submitted (goptions)?  Can you post the full log.  Also, try putting the password into the DSN setup and I'm sure you've tested the connection there to make sure it works. The code in general is correct - `libname test odbc dsn=fpt schema=dbo;`

Comment: @Reeza I will post the log as soon as possible. But my libname statement is just a random statement - do I need to refer to something specific?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'my libname is a just a random statement'.

Comment: Ok sorry for that.
My libname is test, e.i. i wrote in the code:
'libname test'
I meant that i do not know if test is the thing to write here (i just wrote a random word)

Comment: Well, its the name you want to call the library, so test is fine.  It can be anything that is under 8 chars and all character.

Comment: Thank you for that. I uploaded the whole log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the libname statement.  This causes SAS to think the goptions statement (which is added by EG) is part of the libname statement.

Comment: All I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `DSN` switch for the `LIBNAME` statement.

I think you need `DATASRC` instead.

[Source](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001355231.htm)